# FontAwesome loads from weblink, but locally fails on xCode

Tags: html, css, xcode, font-awesome

I'm using fontAwesome inside my xCode project, I'm loading a local html file, with some custom css styles, I need to add some icons defined in fontAwesome as well, Problem is if I provide website link in HTML header it loads the font, if give local CSS link in HTML header it wouldn't load, while I've made sure that all those files are added in my project & target membership is also set to project.

```
<head>
    <link href='../fonts/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>
```

it doesn't work. while the files are added as shown in screen shot.[image: Image Showing FontAwesome assets added in Project] 
But this works fine.

```
<head>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The css files need to be in your css folder, the pathway they take in the font awesome css file is   `../webfonts/whateverfontyouwant` the other files should be in a webfonts folder at the same level as your css. This from font awesome downloaded just now, if you have an older version just open the css files and you see the paths they take.

Comment: Yeah I saw the path and changed those according to my project hierarchy, but didn't work. Also tried you suggested solution but doesn't work.

Comment: When did you download font awesome, does it have anything to do with the version? 4.7.0 is an older version. In the new version things have changed some, some of my icons stopped working until I changed `fa` to `fas`

Comment: I intentionally downloaded older version 4.7.0, I know Version 5.0.12 is out there.

Comment: my confusion is regarding `href='../fonts/font-awesome.min.css'` do we really need to mention folder path here, since after installing on device, all the assets lie in same directory.

Comment: The only time you don't need the path is when the files are on the same level as your html file. If the font awesome css resides where your html is and not in a folder then no, but if it is in a folder called css or fonts then definitely. If your fonts folder is the first folder you have to click to get to the file then you don't need the `../` it would simply be `href="fonts/font-awesome.min.css"`

Comment: Okay, although this doesn't matter on iOS, I had to provide bundle URL for css file to load the css file, although it doesn't work for fontAwesome because @font-face works for web environment as per my understanding, So I'm using `<link href>` to load fontAwesome icon inside application.